# How to execute a local file from GWT?

Tags: gwt

I want to run a third-party application from gwt for manipulating a local file and after this send file to server. I released the feature for uploading and sending file to server, but between these steps I want to change something in this file (with 3-rd party application installed on client machine). The main problem is that the applet cannot be used because nor Chrome, nor Mozilla do not support it. Are there some examples of other tools and technologies to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FileReader and FileWriter api can be used to work with local files. I think the htmt5rocks has a good example of how this can be done with javascript. These processes can be used with GWT elemental FileReader and Writer. I've added links to the javadoc below.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

http://docs.sencha.com/gxt/4.x/javadoc/gwt-2.7.0/index.html?elemental/html/FileReader.html
http://docs.sencha.com/gxt/4.x/javadoc/gwt-2.7.0/index.html?elemental/html/FileWriter.html

Answer (score 0):

Answer is simple: GWT is client-side technology. You cannot run 3rd party application installed on client side, access local drive files or so. 
If you want to change some local file fromt GWT application, then you need to expose Java Applet, do operation on server side and then process it.
Why are you saying Firefox and Chrome don't support it?

Comment: From official Java site:
Chrome no longer supports NPAPI (technology required for Java applets)
https://java.com/en/download/faq/chrome.xml

Comment: You are right. I didn't know about Chrome. Just read about Firefox that Mozilla is planning to shutdown Applet support till the end of 2016: https://blog.mozilla.org/futurereleases/2015/10/08/npapi-plugins-in-firefox/.

What files will be processed in this application? Images? PDF? What is the purpose?

Comment: It is kind of signing some xml files. On server I must know that the file comes from "good" client. I know that it can be implemented in other mode, but now I'm interested in manipulation data from my gwt application. I heard about JNLP (JavaWS) but as I know this also is not so good in my case.